# Test if lines are in regression CI R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, model, regression

I have a dataset that I am plotting with a linear regression (just by `geom_smooth()`). I also have a list slopes and intercepts for other lines. I'm wondering what the best way is to test whether these other lines fall inside the CI of the regression. Real dataset will have many lines to test, so I'm hoping there is some way to test en masse.

```
library(tidyverse)    
# sample data
set.seed(0)
df = tibble(
  x = runif(20,min=5,max=10),
  y = x + rnorm(20,mean=2,sd=3)
)


# df of lines
lines.df <- data.frame(line = c("line 1","line 2","line 3","line 4"),
                       slope = c(.9,1.2,1.4,1.1),
                       intercept = c(2.5,-.5,-.44,0)) 


# plot
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", level = 0.95, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black")+
  geom_abline(data=lines.df,aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept,color=line))
```

[image]

We can see above that lines 1, 2, & 4 are within CI of this regression, but line 3 is not. How can I test this (visually or otherwise) to add a y/n column in my lines.df as to whether they will be in this confidence interval or not?

The only idea I have so far is to create a regression model, calculate CI, then mutate a column in the lines.df extrapolating that line and adding "if y(line1) at x=0 is between y(model(0)±CI(0)) & y(line1) at x=.5 is between y(model(.5)±CI(.5)) & y(line1) at x=1 is between y(model(1)±CI(1))" then insideCI=="yes". But that is pretty clunky and stupid, so I'm thinking there has to be a better way.

For the record, this does not need to be graphical, that's just the easiest way for me to explain what I am looking for.

It would be best for the code to be in dplyr/tidyverse syntax if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could try something along these lines. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55505/144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confidence band you get from ggplot is the predicted values of the fitted +/- 1.96*SE. So you need to check for every predicted values of your lines, it is < 1.96 * SE. To illustrate this the SE (sorry not very good with ggplots) :

```
df = df[order(df$x),]
fit = lm(y~x,data=df)
pred=predict(fit,se=TRUE)
plot(df,pch=20)
lines(df$x,fit$fitted.values)
lines(df$x,pred$fit+1.96*pred$se.fit,lty=8)
lines(df$x,pred$fit-1.96*pred$se.fit,lty=8)
for(i in 1:nrow(lines.df)){
with(lines.df,abline(b=slope[i],a=intercept[i],col=terrain.colors(4)[i]))
}
```

[image]

Then we go through your data, first storing the fitted + SE:

```
library(broom)
res = augment(fit)
# A tibble: 20 x 9
       y     x .fitted .se.fit .resid   .hat .sigma  .cooksd .std.resid
   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
 1  6.64  5.31    7.00   0.981 -0.366 0.204    2.23 0.00455      -0.189
 2  8.28  5.88    7.55   0.816  0.738 0.141    2.23 0.0110        0.366
 3  6.77  6.01    7.66   0.782 -0.890 0.130    2.22 0.0144       -0.439
 4  9.16  6.03    7.68   0.777  1.48  0.128    2.20 0.0388        0.728
```

And then we go through the lines, using purrr and tidyr, (apologies in advance, since you prefer a dplyr/tidyverse solution, and I am not so well versed in those):

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

lines.df %>% nest(param=c(slope,intercept)) %>%
# calculates values according to slopes 
mutate(pred = map(param,~.x$slope*df$x +.x$intercept),
# calculate the difference between these values and the actual fit 
       deviation_from_lm=map(pred,~abs(.x-res$.fitted)),
#check all of them within 1.96*se
       within=map_lgl(deviation_from_lm,~all(.x<=1.96*res$.se.fit))
)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  line   param            pred       deviation_from_lm within
  <fct>  <list>           <list>     <list>            <lgl> 
1 line 1 <tibble [1 × 2]> <dbl [20]> <dbl [20]>        TRUE  
2 line 2 <tibble [1 × 2]> <dbl [20]> <dbl [20]>        TRUE  
3 line 3 <tibble [1 × 2]> <dbl [20]> <dbl [20]>        FALSE 
4 line 4 <tibble [1 × 2]> <dbl [20]> <dbl [20]>        TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! And purr/tidyr are both part of the tidyverse, so this is the exact kind of workflow I was hoping for. I need to get better at the map() functions. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome ! glad it was useful for you in some sense